# Не работает отключение `disabled` у `select` тега

Tags: javascript, html, form

Не работает отключение `disabled` у `select` тега.

HTML разметка:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <label for="user">UserName
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" required>
    </label>
    <label for="psw">Password
        <input type="password" required>
    </label>
    <label for="gender">
        Male<input type="Radio" Name="Gender" Value="Male" id="male" required>
        Female<input type="Radio" Name="Gender" Value="Female" id="female" required>
    </label>
    <label for="selMALE">Прически у мужчин
        <select name="selMALE" id="selMALE" disabled>
            <option value="Британка">Британка</option>
            <option value="Бокс">Бокс</option>
            <option value="Полубокс">Полубокс</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label for="selFEMALE" >Прически у женщин
        <select name="selFEMALE" id="selFEMALE" disabled>
            <option value="Пикси">Пикси</option>
            <option value="Ассиметричная">Ассиметричная</option>
            <option value="Шапочка">Шапочка</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <a href="javascript:s()"><button>Submit</button></a>
</form>
```

JavaScript Код:

```
var f = document.myForm;
var radio = f.Gender.value;
if (radio == 'Male') {
    f.selMALE.disabled = false;
} else if(radio == 'Female'){
    f.selFEMALE.disabled = false;
}

function s(){
    f.submit();
}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что отключение не работает?

Comment: не работает так не работает ))

Comment: а я говорю, что работает. Какие у тебя доказательства, что не работает? **Почему** ты думаешь, что не работает? Может работает. Как ты определяешь?

Comment: А тебе надо, чтобы по клику на submit отключался disabled?

Comment: в хроме пробую когда выбираю Male у меня не включается select. нет не по клику submit

Comment: `f.Gender.onchange=function(){...}`

Comment: не сработал или может я неправильно делаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, лейблу с gender задать id и по клику на него уже проверять, какое radio выбрано:

```js
var f = document.getElementById('myForm');
var sex = document.getElementById('sex');

sex.onclick = function() {
  var radio = f.Gender.value;
  if (radio == 'Male') {
      f.selMALE.disabled = false;
      f.selFEMALE.disabled = true;
  } else if(radio == 'Female'){
      f.selFEMALE.disabled = false;
      f.selMALE.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <label for="user">UserName
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" required>
    </label>
    <label for="psw">Password
        <input type="password" required>
    </label>
    <label id="sex" for="gender">
        Male<input type="Radio" Name="Gender" Value="Male" id="male" required>
        Female<input type="Radio" Name="Gender" Value="Female" id="female" required>
    </label>
    <label for="selMALE">Прически у мужчин
        <select name="selMALE" id="selMALE" disabled>
            <option value="Британка">Британка</option>
            <option value="Бокс">Бокс</option>
            <option value="Полубокс">Полубокс</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label for="selFEMALE" >Прически у женщин
        <select name="selFEMALE" id="selFEMALE" disabled>
            <option value="Пикси">Пикси</option>
            <option value="Ассиметричная">Ассиметричная</option>
            <option value="Шапочка">Шапочка</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое помог очень !!!!